# How to make some rows of a column empty in the asp.net controls while binding

Tags: asp.net

I have data like below

```
     Header1  Header2
     Main1      Sub1
     Main1      Sub2
     Main1      Sub3
     Main2      Sub1
     Main2      Sub2
     Main2      Sub3
```

I need to display data in ASP.NET server Control like below

[image]

how to do in asp.net server controls (any)

The html code is below.

```
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
<tr>
<td>
Header1
</td><td>Header2</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>
Main1
</td><td>sub1</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>

</td><td>sub2</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>

</td><td>sub3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Main2
</td><td>sub1</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>

</td><td>sub2</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>

</td><td>sub3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

get the data  in datatable than...do it like this...

```
Datatable dt=Getdata();//custom function to get data in datatable

List<string> list=new List<string>;

foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
if(list.Contains(dr["Header1"].ToString())
dr["Header1"]="";
else
list.Add(dr["Header1"].ToString());
}
```

After this set source of gridview to this datatable.